# mongodb - chunk size = 64MB - compressed or uncompressed?

Tags: mongodb, sharding, chunks

The Mongodb 3.6 documentation states

> The default chunk size in MongoDB is 64 megabytes

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-data-partitioning

Is this compressed or uncompressed? I assume uncompressed, but just to be sure.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on storage engine your are using.

With WiredTiger, MongoDB supports compression for all collections and indexes.

By default, collection data in WiredTiger uses snappy block compression.

Compression settings are also configurable on a per-collection and per-index basis during collection and index creation.